# ITopologicalOperator.Intersect, how does this work?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, intersection, asp.net, arcgis-web-adf

I'm trying to intersect all features of a layer with another's but I'm getting the web ADF application stuck while executing the "ConstructUnion" function

Here's the code I've written so far

```
// create a geometrybag for layer1
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry geometryBag = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.GeometryBagClass();
geometryBag.SpatialReference = m_firstLayerFirstfeatureIGeometry.SpatialReference;
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometryCollection geometryCollection = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometryCollection)geometryBag;
// Cycle all features of first layer and add them to the collection
foreach (DataRow m_dr in m_firstLayerfeatureGraphics.Rows)
{
    // Takes this feature's geometry
    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry adfFeature =
        m_firstLayerfeatureGraphics.GeometryFromRow(m_dr) as ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.Geometry.Geometry;
    // convert to a igeometry object
    ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry m_tempfeatureIGeometry =
    ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources.ArcGISServer.Local.Converter.ToIGeometry(adfFeature, ctx);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("m_firstLayerfeatureGraphics +1 ");
    object missing = Type.Missing;
    geometryCollection.AddGeometry(m_tempfeatureIGeometry, ref missing, ref
    missing);
}
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.ITopologicalOperator mtopo1 = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.PolygonClass();
// FOLLOWING LINE BLOCKS APPLICATION
mtopo1.ConstructUnion((ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnumGeometry)geometryBag);
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is there any COM error message or does it really just sit on that line forever?

Comment: It just sits on that line forever. Occasionally everything crashes with no error (w3smp.exe crash or something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the ArcObject instances (`GeometryBagClass` at the beginning and `PolygonClass` near the end of your code snippet) on the ArcGIS Server SOC by using [IServerContext.CreateObject](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/003z/003z00000056000000.htm). Your current code creates these objects on the web server (or wherever your ADF app is running), which requires a lot of marshalling which in many cases seems to never finish.

You already have the reference to the server context in the `ctx` variable, so you are basically all set. Once all the ArcObjects are created on the ArcGIS Server, your problem is likely to be solved.